# How to change keyboard layouts in Ubuntu Touch with more than two layouts configured?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, keyboard-layout, auto-completion

In my system settings I configured 4 keyboard layouts. But when using the touch keyboard I can only switch between two of them.
That also excludes word completion for the missing ones.
Did I miss something in the configuration or is it a malfunction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Long press on the keyboard layout (globe) key.
   [image: long-press-golbe-key]
2. A pop-up menu should appear showing all the added layouts. Tap on the check box next to the preferred language.
   [image: list-languages]
3. Layout should change to the preferred one now.
   [image]

By the way, a short tap swaps to the lastly selected layout.